# Matter with try: and except: in python

Tags: python

While I searching for a piece of code, I found something like this:

```
try:
   job_bulletin_date = pd.to_datetime(...) #Just an example
except:
   job_bulletin_date = pd.to_datetime(...) #Just an exapmle
```

I mean they write the same code below `try:` and `except:` Are there any advantage behind this ?

Can we replace it with the `pass` function as below ?

```
try:
   job_bulletin_date = pd.to_datetime(...)
except:
   pass
```

Comment: were the arguments the same?

Comment: Einstein: `insanity is doing the same thing over and over again and expecting a different result`

Comment: If the arguments to `to_datetime` are 100% identical, it seems pretty silly to do this. But it might make sense if the function isn't deterministic, in which case calling it a second time might do something different. For example, a call to `requests.get`.

Comment: Yes might see something like this but with a time delay e.g. `except: time.sleep(60)  # wait a bit; try_again` etc. Using `pass` is obviously not the same as 'trying again'

Comment: Rare scenario but I've had an issue in my code, and when I `try/catch` it the issue disappeared and the exception was never raised.  Could be used for an additional retry for these timing issues?

Comment: In any case, your two code blocks do _not_ have identical behavior. if `pd.to_datetime` raises a TypeError, for instance, then your first block will crash with a TypeError on the final line, and your second block won't crash at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to, but it will change the behaviour of the code. The except will call the function again after the initial function threw an exception for whatever reason, but it won't if you use `pass`. This will only matter in three circumstances:

1. **`pd.to_datetime(...)` is a function with side effects**, or a function is being called in the arguments or body of `pd.to_datetime` that has side effects. This means that it affects some global context outside of it's scope, such as a global variable or database. The name of the function makes this sound unlikely, but it's worth checking because it might be that the first try made some change to the context that allows the second try to pass through.
2. **`pd.to_datetime()` accesses a variable or resource that may change over time**. For example, it may have timed out trying to make a request to a web service, or looking for a file on the file system that it expects to be created by some other process. This would mean that subsequent calls of the same function could result in different behaviour because the context has changed since the last call. Again, this seems unlikely, but it is worth checking for.
3. **The arguments to `pd.to_datetime()` are different on the second call**, meaning the behaviour of the function will likely be different.

If none of these circumstances is true, then you can likely remove the second call to the function. I'd recommend putting something more useful than `pass` in there though, even just a print statement would be much more helpful to any future users when debugging.

Comment: Related to 1), `pd.to_datetime` itself is pure, but impure functions are being called to create its arguments in each case, i.e., `pd.to_datetime(some_impure_function())`.